# navbar width automatically becoming 5px or so bigger than the body somehow....?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have these TWO websites which I just realised both have this issue, and it lies with the navbar. When on mobile device size they get these annoying scrollable white borders on just the right side.... changing padding and margin of anything doesn't help at all. But changing position: fixed; to relative fixes it but obviously makes the navbar not stick. So for some reason the z axis layer of the document is getting a bigger overall width than the body or normal y and x axis divs.....?

Site 1: http://myleisure.com.au 
Site 2: http://danceforovariancancer.com.au

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your navbar being the problem. I can't reproduce it on my phone to know for sure, but I did test it on OSX Chrome at 320px wide.

I went into the dev tools and either deleted elements or manually added `overflow: hidden;` to find out where it made a difference. From what I saw, various minor problems are hidden throughout the sites that are causing overflow (and thus, scrollbars).

On the first site, this particular rule seems to be the actual culprit...

In "css.css":

```
.col-centered {
    ...
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

On the second site, you have nested `.row`s. A `.container` has 15px of padding to offset child `.row`'s -15px margins. But `.row`s do not have the same padding, so they cannot be nested.

- Your nesting problem appears at the "BONUS EVENT" heading within the
  Acts section.
- Also, add the `img-responsive` class to the image of Jane Hill's
  signature in the About section.
- Finally, at 320px width, the email provided in the footer is too long
  to fit. I would recommend that you change the paragraph wording and swap it out for a mailto link like:

  `<a href="mailto:emma.robinson@ovariancancer.net.au">Emma Robinson</a>`

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth analysis it was really doing my head in. Thanks for the tip on the mail to link, I've never thought to use them, cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {width:100%; overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Comment: Note: While this probably fixes the problem for now, this is not a good permanent solution. Instead of finding the source of the extra space, this tactic just hides it and you are likely to not only run into the same problem again on future projects, but you may have other problems appear as a result.

Comment: This has been suggested numerous times on this site to cure this exact issue. On mobile phones you can swipe right and left and see white space. I don't see how adding these styles would be detrimental.

Comment: All content that is too wide to fit on the screen just gets cut off with this technique. In particular, this may be a problem for non-wrapping content such as images, tables, non-breaking text (e.g. long emails), etc. Also, if you disable horizontal scrollbars, you no longer have a way to instantly know about the existence of things on a page that are too wide.

Comment: Ok but with bootstrap it's hardly an issue since it's responsive and nothing should be off the page. You can still add overflow-x:scroll to things like tables and stuff...

Comment: Exactly. "Nothing **should** be off the page". Human errors happen, though - We may not use bootstrap properly sometimes, we may make breaking custom CSS changes, or we might simply forget to add a bootstrap class.